# mysql query to select between previous and next month

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Trying to select all days from the start of the previous month to the end of the next month:

```
USE test;

SELECT *  FROM  MyTable
WHERE col_date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)) 
             AND DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL +1 MONTH))
```

Its saying my syntax in incorrect, but I saw snippet of the DATE_ADD function being used like this.

Comment: Exactly what error message are you getting?  Please paste error messages rather than paraphrasing.

Comment: Try `BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND (NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  date_sub()

```
date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

So the query should be something as

```
USE test;
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE 
col_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)  AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Here how it looks like in mysql

```
mysql> select date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) as previous_month , date_add(now(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH) as next_month;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| previous_month      | next_month          |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2014-05-06 22:27:35 | 2014-07-06 22:27:35 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH as previous_month ,NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH as next_month ;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| previous_month      | next_month          |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2014-05-06 22:28:39 | 2014-07-06 22:28:39 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Should I use DATE_SUB instead of  user2989408's suggestion? Is there a difference?

Comment: there is no difference its upto you which function you want to use